# Add clickable buttons to a custom DataGridViewCell control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I made a custom DataGridViewColumn control together with its DataGridViewCell controls. 
The idea is to dynamically create the contents of the cell, which consists of a series of clickable function buttons, upon databinding. The number and kinds of buttons depend on the data value passed.

For this, I override the Paint method of the DataGridViewCell and check the formattedValue on its contents and draw buttons accordingly. However, these buttons are "dead" and not clickable, so the question is how to make them clickable, i.e. how do I add a handler for the click event?

Do I have to override the cell's OnClick method and then try to pinpoint which button exactly is clicked? Is this even possible? Are there better ways?

This is what I've got so far:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As Graphics, clipBounds As Rectangle, cellBounds As Rectangle, rowIndex As Integer, cellState As DataGridViewElementStates, value As Object, formattedValue As Object, errorText As String, cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle, paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)

    MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

    Dim cellBackground As New SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor)
    graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds)
    cellBackground.Dispose()

    PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle)

    Dim sValue As String = formattedValue.ToString()

    If (sValue.Contains("ViewAsPDF")) Then

        Dim buttonArea As Rectangle = cellBounds
        Dim buttonAdjustment As Rectangle = Me.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle)
        buttonArea.X += buttonAdjustment.X
        buttonArea.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y
        buttonArea.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height
        buttonArea.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width
        buttonArea.Width = buttonArea.Width / 4
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea, PushButtonState.Default)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "PDF", Me.DataGridView.Font, buttonArea, SystemColors.ControlText)

    End If

   'etcetera 

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not clickable"? Is it give user the feeling of click or handle events similar to normal button.

Comment: Don't you need to add a handler for the click event of each button you create?

Comment: @Supersnake Yes! But how do I achieve that in the current setup? I don't see any way of getting hold of the button I am drawing, so I can assign a handler...

Comment: @Junaith I have edited the question, so it is clearer that I'm looking for ways of binding an event handler.

Comment: Why not use a proper DataGridViewButtonColumn?

Comment: @FedorSteeman, are you drawing multiple buttons in a single cell? Could you post an image to understand better.

Comment: @danish because I need to draw multiple buttons in a single column, as I already wrote. I think the idea is pretty straightforward; the implementation I'm not sure of.

Comment: I think you ambled down the wrong road.  First, you are not adding buttons to the cell, you are just drawing the cell *to look like* it has several buttons.  Real buttons are objects which can have events, which you could add handlers to.  Custom controls can be added to DGV cols, but since it is cell oriented, it is usually one control per cell/column.  The only way I can think of is to store a template of cell rects then in the cell click event see which rect contains the cursor location.  Far too little is known about the custom DGV to be of much help.  But why not an "Actions" dropdown?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, that was starting to dawn on me. I just don't understand why there is a ButtonRenderer, if you can't create actual Buttons with it? 
Anyways, that dropdownlist/combobox with actions sounds like a great possible alternative. I will see if I can try that, but feel free to create an answer on the basis of that proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have wandered down the wrong road.  Based on the code provided, you are simply drawing  the cells to *look like* they contain buttons.  Since they are not actually objects, they are incapable of raising events.

`I don't understand ButtonRenderer, if you can't create actual Buttons with it`

The `ButtonRender` does not *create* a new button object, it is meant to be used *by* Button objects for drawing.  Often a subclassed a button, will not use it because it employs the existing theme and style which is may be what a you wants to do differently (even the `DataGridViewButtonCell` does not use it -- at least not directly).

From the code provided, it seems to work out each button on the fly each time rather than drawing from some collection or definition.   What if the "action" list needs to vary based on the row (e.g. different actions for a DOC, XLS or Image row)?  Doing so, would seem to take a great deal of code.

---

Your current course may not be impossible, but it is not trivial either.  You  *might* be able to create a collection of virtual buttons (basically the Rect from when it was drawn) and render them as you have done.  Then in the cell-click event, translate/adjust the X position to see which rectangle contains `thisPt.X` to determine which related action to take.

There are "issues" still such as what happens when the user resizes the column? What about when the button list varies by some other cell value (DOC vs XLS vs IMG vs PDF)?  This would require a collection of button sets...and a fair amount of code.

This is not to say it cant be done, but it seems like a great deal of code would be required to make it even a little flexible.

---

**`Are there better ways?`**

I think so.

A simpler, existing solution might be to use the existing `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to store "Actions" or "Activities".  It seems a bit less cluttered and more user friendly:

[image]

It takes only a small amount of code to provide a different list for each animal:

```
' dogs like to go for walks
Private ActsCan() As String = {"Feed", "Pet", "Bathe", "Brush", "Take for Walk"}
' no walks or baths for cats
Private ActsFel() As String = {"Feed", "Pet", "Baby-Talk To", "Brush"}
' never bathe a Mugwai, comb rather than brush
Private ActsMug() As String = {"Feed", "Pet", "Baby-Talk To", "Comb"}
Private ActsGrem() As String = {"Hide From", "Strangle"}
...
Private Sub dgv_RowEnter(sender As Object, 
          e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowEnter

    Dim dgvCBO As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    dgvCBO = CType(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColActs"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
    dgvCBO.Items.Clear()
    Select Case dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colSpecies").Value.ToString
        Case "Canine"
            dgvCBO.Items.AddRange(ActsCan)
        Case "Feline"
            dgvCBO.Items.AddRange(ActsFel)
        Case "Mugwai"
            dgvCBO.Items.AddRange(ActsMug)
        Case "Gremlin"
            dgvCBO.Items.AddRange(ActsGrem)
    End Select
End Sub
```

A class to encapsulate most of *that* might be nice for unbound DGVs.  It could be optimized not to rebuild the list when the trigger value for `thisRow` is the same as the last.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and report back!

Comment: Priorities changed and I haven't had time to try this, but I am quite certain it is the way forward!

Comment: Because the value being passed to the cell upon databinding, I have been able to do it with even less code and it looks promising! 
However, that gives me a subsequent error upon databinding, because the cell value is not valid for being bound to a combobox (argumentexception). An example value would be: "Labels, ActionCard, Where, Archive, InternalComment, More".

Comment: typically, for bound controls the list is static and bound to a Code Table or query. IIRC, MSDN has a couple good examples, depending on what you are trying to do in your version.

Comment: Actually, the value I am trying to bind is a form of enum, which apparently is not accepted as valid value. So I am thinking of making a custom DataGridViewComboBoxCell and set the value to something acceptable. I am just not sure what that would be. An array was not accepted in any case.

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach. Only implementing the ui.

[image]